# Share link to Facebook Messenger

Tags: swift, facebook, facebook-messenger

I have code that shares a url (with a description) to other apps. This code works just fine for Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, etc EXCEPT it does not work for Facebook Messenger.  In Facebook messenger, it is as if the url does not exist.  It loads up the text, but not the URL.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareText, UserService.sharedInstance.sharingLink(profile)], applicationActivities: nil)
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view

let sourceRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 1)
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sourceRect
self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This block of code has been in my app for awhile, and it was only recently noticed that it did not work with Facebook Messenger.

Does FBM needs some kind of custom handling in order for it to work correctly?  If so, where can I see an example / documentation for this?  Why does my code correctly work for every app EXCEPT FBM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook Messenger only handles the **string parameter** of `UIActivityViewController` from the two parameters you've given. You should include the URL in the shared text, like this:

```
let shareText = "Check out this app! http://example.com"
```

Comment: So, how come what I am doing works for *every other app* just fine?  Why is FBM _special_ ?

Comment: Can I detect when the app is facebook messenger and append it to that string?

Comment: You cannot change the activity items after the activity controller is present. I'm not sure why FBM is like this, my guess is that it only adds a URL to the message when it detects the address in the text.

Comment: IT is unfortunate that FBM ignores the URL, unlike other apps.  Your solution does work, but now some apps don't build link previews using this method.  I'll have to see what else I can do to improve this